# Express Mongoose populate pre typescript what type?

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I'm updating an old javascript express app
to a brand new typescript app.
I've a problem with typing populate

```
/* Kind of like a middleware function after creating our schema (since we have access to next) */
/* Must be a function declaration (not an arrow function), because we want to use 'this' to reference our schema */
const autoPopulatePostedBy = function (next) {
  this.populate('postedBy', '_id username avatar');
  this.populate('comments.postedBy', '_id username avatar');
  next();
};

/* We're going to need to populate the 'postedBy' field virtually every time we do a findOne / find query, so we'll just do it as a pre hook here upon creating the schema */
postSchema.pre<IPostSchema>('findOne', autoPopulatePostedBy).pre<IPostSchema>('find', autoPopulatePostedBy);
/* Create index on keys for more performant querying/post sorting */

postSchema.index({ postedBy: 1, createdAt: 1 });

export default model<IPostSchema>('Post', postSchema);
```

I've got error for next and this, typescript point out
to type any and for pre

```
Argument of type '"findOne"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | MongooseDocumentMiddleware | MongooseDocumentMiddleware[]'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterized type for the `pre` hooks need to be of type `Query<ResultType, Doctype extends Document<any, {}>, THelpers={}>`

Whatever type you've parameterized your your `IPostSchema` to should suffice as the Doctype/ResultType here.

e.g.:

```
postSchema.pre<Query<IPostInterfaceDocument, IPostInterfaceDocument>>('findOne', .....
```

You'll need to import `Query` from `mongoose` as well.